# Find order of points to make a quadrilateral

Tags: algorithm, geometry

While giving [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18029667/752320) to ["Given four coordinates check whether it forms a square"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18006377/752320), I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18009503/752320), which checks for a parallelogram, then for a right angle. This works, but only if the points coming in are in a certain order. Namely, P1 and P3 must be "opposite" from each other, not adjacent.

So, the question. If the four points coming in could be in any order, how can you sort them so that they are in the "correct" order to make a quadrilateral?

The simplest thing I could come up with is something like:

```
for each valid permutation of points[]{ // see below for "valid"
    generate line segment for:
        points[0] -> points[1]
        points[1] -> points[2]
        points[2] -> points[3]
        points[3] -> points[0]
    if any line segment crosses another // use cross product
        continue
    return permutation
}
```

I know that most permutations are simple rotations(`0123 == 1230`), so I can keep the first point 'fixed'. Also, I think I could cut it down by only considering what points are in the `0` and `2` of each permutation spots, since the order of the other two don't matter. For example, if `0123` is a polygon, `0321` is also, since it generates the same segments.

This leaves me with only three basic permutations to check:

- `[0,1,2,3]`
- `[0,1,3,2]`
- `[0,2,1,3]`

Each permutation has six segment-to-segment checks, so that's a total of 18 comparisons.

I can't think of any other way to do this, but it seems like I'm missing something. Is there a better way to do this? The answer given for the square question is good, but if I have to make an additional(up to) 18 checks to verify the points are in the correct order, it would be quicker just to use inter-corner distances.

Comment: Is this question specifically about the quadrilateral for the square problem, do you want a generic solution for all quadrilaterals or is either fine?

Comment: A generic solution would be best. The problem started as "how to figure out how to put them in order to feed to the square problem", but I'm guessing it could have other useful applications.

Comment: I have a silly question: we are talking about 2D points, right?

Comment: @beaker Yes, 2D only for the purposes of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Each permutation has six segment-to-segment checks, so that's a total of 18 comparisons.

You do not need to check all the segments: it would be sufficient to check that segments `[0-2]` and `[1-3]` (i.e. the two diagonals) intersect. You need to check that the segments intersect, not the lines to which the segments belong, i.e. an intersection outside of the segments does not count.

Once you fix the starting point `"A"`, you end up with six possible permutations:

[image]

Two of them (`A-B-D-C` and `A-C-D-B`) are good; the remaining four are bad. You can arrive at a good one with only two checks:

- Check the initial permutation; if it is good, keep it; otherwise
- Swap points 1 and 2, and check the permutation; if it is good, keep it; otherwise
- Revert to the original permutation, swap points 2 and 3, and keep that permutation; it is bound to be "good".

Comment: This makes sense. Two permutation checks, one cross-check per. I don't think it could get much simpler than that.

Comment: Note that ABDC = ACDB, ABCD = ADCB and ACBD = ADBC. Add the 4th line (the line between the 4th and 1st points) and you should see it.

Comment: @Dukeling Right, I skipped the directional symmetry (clockwise vs. counterclockwise) on purpose, to convince myself that the diagram covers all six possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Implement a method called isParallelAndEqual(p0,p1,q0,q1). This checks if lines p1-p1 and q0-q1 are parallel and of equal length.

Given points a,b,c and d, the final result looks like:

ifParallelAndEqual(a,b,c,d)||ifParallelAndEqual(a,c,b,d)

Comment: I'd rather a general solution for a quadrilateral, not necessarily a parallelogram. Agreed that it is useful for that, though.

Comment: In a general quadrilateral the answer might be ambiguous. Consider a case where you have 3 points anywhere and the fourth point is within the triangle prescribed by the first three points. There is no exact answer in this case (or, all combinations of answers are valid)

Comment: True, I suppose I meant convex only. Good point, and something I hadn't considered.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you simply check all of the below until you find one that's true? (that is, check P1 opposite each other point)

```
P3 = P1 + (P2-P1) + (P4-P1)
P2 = P1 + (P3-P1) + (P4-P1)
P4 = P1 + (P2-P1) + (P3-P1)
```

For the square variant, if they happen to be axis-aligned, you can do: (that is, the opposite point is the one which doesn't have a coordinate in common)

```
if (P1.x != P3.x && P1.y != P3.y)
  check P3 = P1 + (P2-P1) + (P4-P1)

if (P1.x != P2.x && P1.y != P2.y)
  check P2 = P1 + (P3-P1) + (P4-P1)

if (P1.x != P4.x && P1.y != P4.y)
  check P4 = P1 + (P2-P1) + (P3-P1)

otherwise return false
```

Comment: Your first point makes the most sense, now that I think about it. The second rejects rotated squares, though.

Comment: The axis-aligned method was the first thing I though of, but it really restrains the usefulness. Nevertheless, +1. Not sure how my brain skipped right over the fact that I could just run the formula three times. Of course, this really only applies to the square/parallelogram issue, not quadrilateral in general.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be simpler to do the following:

1. Check if points `0, 1` and `2` span a triangle (if they are co-linear the quadrilateral is degenerate too)
2. Check the following segments for intersection:

```
[0, 3] and [1, 2]
[1, 3] and [0, 2]
[2, 3] and [0, 1]
```

If none of them intersects, the quadrilateral is non-convex.

Otherwise, you should have exactly one intersecting case. You found your opposite vertices there.

Comment: If `3,0,1` are co-linear(in that order), wouldn't it see `[1,3]` intersect with `[0,2]`? It's the first counterexample I came up with on paper, but I'm worried there may be others. I suppose I could check all the point combinations for co-linearity, but...

Comment: @Geobits I think that depends on the intersection check. If you use the cross product, isn't it easy to find the border cases? (in `[0,1]` means intersection, so exactly 0 or 1 means a border case?)

Comment: True that it depends. With the cross product, you'd have to be very careful if you're using floating-point math. The difference between a valid/degenerate quadrilateral could be very small, and "exactly zero" doesn't work so well.

Answer (score 0):

Here was my solution. I optimized [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18085257/12577883) answer to avoid extra intersection checks.

Given any points ABCD in which any three points are not-colinear, ABC forms a triangle. Then, the lines that form this triangle break up the possible positions for D into zones. From this, we can say that:

1. If AB intersects DC, ADBC is a valid quadrilateral
2. If AD intersects BC, ABDC is a valid quadrilateral
3. Otherwise, ABCD is a valid quadrilateral

```
points = [a,b,c,d];

if (ab.intersects(cd)) {
    points[1] = d;
    points[2] = b;
    points[3] = c;
} else if (bc.intersects(ad)) {
    points[2] = d;
    points[3] = c;
}
```