# Algorithm to find diagonals in a set of 6 segments defined by 4 points forming a convex quadrilateral

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry, 2d

here's a simple problem of 2D computational geometry that I've been unsuccessful to solve:

```
we have four points A, B, C, D defining a CONVEX QUADRILATERAL 

(not a square or a rectangle!)

we know the (x, y) coordinates of each point.
```

There are 6 segments connecting 2 points:

```
AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, CD
```

One of the intersections of these segments will form a point inside the figure: the intersection of the two diagonals.

There are 3 possible for couples of diagonals:

```
[AB] and [CD]
[AC] and [BD]
[AD] and [BC]
```

(see the figure below)

[image: illustration]

I am searching for a simple algorithm to find which of the 3 possible cases is happening when I vary the (x, y) coordinates of A, B, C, D

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding this, but you're trying to find which pair of points are diagonal to each other?

Comment: Without constraints on the 2D positions of the points, there may not be clear "diagonals".  Are the points guaranteed to represent corners of an axis-aligned square (as in your diagrams) or can they be at arbitrary positions?

Comment: Can't you just check for line segment intersections of your 3 pairs? Seems the simplest way to me. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18085257/752320

Comment: @MooseBoys just edited the post, we are in a CONVEX QUADRILATERAL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Take lines AB, AC, AD.
2. Measure angles between them (dot product of two normalized vectors is cosine of angle between them).
   Measure angles CAB, CAD, BAD and find two smallest angles.
3. Those two smallest angles share a side. This side is a diagonal. The points that belong to non-shared sides form another diagonal.

Example.

1. Measure angles BAC, CAD, BAD.
2. BAC and CAD are two smallest angles. (also, sum of the angles BAC and CAD will be equal to angle BAD, so you could check for that too).
3. They share side AC. That makes AC first diagonal, and it means that BD is another diagonal.

**Will not work on concave geometry.**

**better explanation**(with diagram)

[image: diagram]

In this picture, `∠DAB = ∠DAC + ∠BAC`. Therefore, `∠DAC < ∠DAB` and `∠BAC < ∠DAB`.
AC is shared, and is diagonal. BC is another diagonal.

I.e. in all cases, two small angles form "big" angles, and their shared side splits "big" angle into two small angles. For a single vertex in convex quad there are only 3 angles to check, and that'll be enough to find all diagonals.

**vector normalization**.

Normalized vector is vector with length of `1.0`. 
To normalize vector, scale it by factor of `1.0/length`. Length can be calculated with dot product.

`normalizedVector = scale(originalVector, 1/length(originalVector))` (watch out for vectors with length of 0 here.)
`length(vector) = sqrtf(dotProduct(vector, vector))`
"scaling" a vector is multiplying it with scalar.

Comment: problem greatly solved and easy to code in c++ under this form, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The points {A,B,C,D} form 4 triangles:  ABC, ABD, ACD, and BCD.  Computing their orientation yields a 4-bit binary signature which determines the order of the convex hull as follows:

```
       signature key: "+" for counterclockwise, "-" for clockwise

A A A B
B B C C   convex hull, in counterclockwise order:
C D D D

+ + + +   quadrilateral ABCD
+ + + -   triangle ABD (C is internal)
+ + - +   triangle ABC (D is internal)
+ + - -   quadrilateral ABDC
+ - + +   triangle BCD (A is internal)
+ - + -   (should not happen)
+ - - +   quadrilateral ADBC
+ - - -   triangle ADC (B is internal)

          (inverting all signature bits reverses hull orientation)

- + + +   triangle CDA (B is internal)
- + + -   quadrilateral CBDA
- + - +   (should not happen)
- + - -   triangle DCB (A is internal)
- - + +   quadrilateral CDBA
- - + -   triangle CBA (D is internal)
- - - +   triangle DBA (C is internal)
- - - -   quadrilateral DCBA
```

You can compute the orientation (clockwise or counterclockwise) of any given triangle as follows:

```
struct Point {
  float x, y;
  Point(float xx,float yy):x(xx),y(yy){}
};
Point operator+(Point A, Point B) { return Point(A.x+B.x,A.y+B.y); }
Point operator-(Point A, Point B) { return Point(A.x-B.x,A.y-B.y); }

float orientation(Point A, Point B, Point C) {
  Point AB = B - A;
  Point AC = C - A;
  return AB.x*AC.y - AB.y*AC.x; // 2-D equivalent to the 3-D cross-product
}
```

The function `orientation(A,B,C)` returns a positive value if triangle ABC is counter-clockwise, negative if it is clockwise, and zero if it is degenerate.  (If your coordinate system is left-handed instead of right-handed, then clockwise is exchanged for counterclockwise, but this doesn't really matter...)

Comment: very impressive answer

Answer (score 1):

The simples I can figure out:

1. Take point A.
2. Measure slopes of vectors AB,AC,AD.
3. See the relations between them.

   ```
     Case 1: SAC>SAB>SAD,
     Case 2: SAB>SAC>SAD,
     Case 3: SAB>SAD>SAC.
   ```

   Take into account 360 degree difference.

P.S. I'm not sure whether you care about quadrilaterals with angles > 180. If yes you have to consider them additionally.

Comment: If it is convex, there can be no angle > 180. Once there is an angle > 180, the figure stops being convex and becomes concave.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
I think you are to start with defining the convex hull points and lines. [Wiki-Graham Scan Alg.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan) may be used to determine the line segments that participate in creating the convex hull. Once you have determined the line segments, the diagonals can easily be found. Using the example in the link, the following line segments can be stored (in the sequence determined by the algorithm) in an array (each pair of points define a line segment):

```
P,A
A,B
B,D
D,P
```

From this array, you can get the diagonal points immediately to be P,B and A,D.

This algorithm does not require angle calculation and has no assumption about the area shape.

Comment: You don't need something this this complicated for something this trivial. Simple geometry from school course will work just fine.

Comment: The simpler the solution the more elegant it is :)

Answer (score 0):

If your coordinates are :

```
0,0
0,1
1,0
1,1
```

you could recognize that the ones with the same x and y coordinates form a diagonal, and the ones with varying x and y coords form a diagonal.

so if the coordinates are:

```
1,1
1,3
3,1
3,3
```

then the letters at a,b where a=b form one, and the ones at a,b where a!=b form one, so
the letter at 1,1 and 3,3 would be one and so would 1,3 and 3,1.

Just note that this only works if it's a square.

also, for any case, you could do this:

you could match up the pairs that DO NOT share a same coordinate.

for

```
A--B
|  |
C--D
```

you would be able to know that A and D are a pair because A and C share an X coordinate, and A and B share a Y coordinate.

No coordinate in common == diagonals. (for any square or rectangle in this fashion.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention it is a CONVEX QUADRILATERAL