# Algorithm for finding Quatraples which form a Square?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

There are n points in 2-D space.  Can you suggest efficient algorithm to output all the quadruples which form square.

Comment: It would be a good idea if you accept answers to your other questions that correctly led you to a solution.

Answer (score 2):

There is simple O(n^3) algorithm.
Take a pair of points (black). For this pair we can check other points as possible candidates to form a square - green and red places. If we have found both green points or both red points then output square(s) formed by initial pair and by these points. Pseudocode:

```
for i = 0 to n-4 do
  for j = i+1 to n-3 do
     Calc Green1Coordinates
     Green1 = 0 
     ... the same for Green2 and Reds
     for k = j+1 to n-1 do
        if P[k] = Green1Coordinates then
           Green1 = k
        else
          the same for Green2 and Reds
     if Green1 and Green2 then
       outputSquare(i,j,Green1,Green2)
     if Red1 and Red2 then
       outputSquare(i,j,Red1,Red2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this in O(n^2 logn).

For each point, sort all other points by distance. Since a square needs two equidistant points and one that is that distance times `sqrt(2)`, you can easily find candidate groups. Once you do, there are [several methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18006377/752320) to check a group for squareness.

```
for each point a
    sort other points by distance to a
    find duplicate pair b, c                      
    for each duplicate pair
        find point d with distance *= sqrt(2)     
        if d exists, check for square a, b, c, d
```

If you're concerned with the distance measurements, you can use squared distance to omit the `sqrt()` function. If you do, just check that the hypotenuse distance is times `2` rather than `sqrt(2)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple algorithm to check for quadruples:-

1. sort all pairs of points according to slopes breaking ties with lesser length one coming   first.
2. scan the sorted list and check for adjacent pair to current pair with same length & slope.
3. if found such pair find its parallel distance and check if it is same as length. If so then the quadruple form a square.
4. if not found continue with next pair in the list
5. Do this for all pairs in sorted list.

Time complexity: Average case `O(N^2*logN)`

space complexity: `O(N^2)`